# Car Color-Temperature Duplicate Declined

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, duplicates

The question from today [How much difference to interior temperature would a white car roof make?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/229145/) says essentially "My car is hot so I'm thinking of painting the roof white. How much would that affect the temperature?"

This question from Feb 2014 [Temperature behavior over time of black or white cars in hot, sunny regions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/96574/) says "Some claim the black car will stay hotter [than the white car], some others claim it will be the same whatever the color. Do all cars have the same temperature inside in the long run, or are some of them hotter?"

I marked the new question as duplicate but it was declined. Why?

Comment: I have no idea why the duplicate was declined (there are a couple possibilities, like high-rep users all voting to leave open, making the system auto-decline the flag). That said, I think you were correct, and I voted to close as duplicate. Unfortunately, 4 other close voters chose the engineering reason (I have no idea how this applies), so this is the message that will be relayed to the asker. The system is far from perfect.

Comment: The [review page for that question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/review/close/113586) corroborates Chris's interpretation to some extent, but it still conflicts somewhat with [this mother-meta post on declined flags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/105395/184688). Since there were four engineering close votes when Chris got to it, the two close-votes on the review queue (with three close votes outside the queue) would have agreed with you on the closure, but not on the reason. Hence the declined flag, I think.

Comment: Related question on [meta.se]: [Details of a declined off-topic flag where the question was still closed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272988/details-of-a-declined-off-topic-flag-where-the-question-was-still-closed).

Comment: Thanks @EmilioPisanty and Chris. If I'm reading the review page correctly (and I'm not even sure why I am able to... isn't that a 3k rep thing?) the most likely sequence was that I flagged as duplicate, three people voted to leave open so the flag was declined and then later five people voted to close. If that's what happened that makes sense and I will delete this question soon, thank you.

Comment: Review pages are public, in the interests of transparency. See [animuson's answer to my question on the mother meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272992/184688) for the details. Don't delete this question, btw - it is a useful marker for the future, and this behaviour was not obvious and not properly documented.